# Serializing a Pygame surface as bytes

Tags: python, serialization, python-3.x, pygame, pygame-surface

What is the easiest way to serialize a Pygame Surface object, and then unserialize bytes back into an identical object? From [the docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) I would guess that `get_view` or `get_buffer` might be useful, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [pygame.surfarray](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html#module-pygame.surfarray)

You can use `pygame.surfarray.array3d()` to get array of pixels
and `pygame.surfarray.make_surface()` to create surface again.

And you can use `pickle`.

If you only need to save surface on disk then use `pygame.image.save()`, `pygame.image.load()`

Comment: Another option is using `pygame.image.tostring` and `pygame.image.fromstring`. `pickle` will not work with standard surfaces.